# Changing state of image view till the user presses on it in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a photo editor app for iOS using swift. I want to make it such that as long as the user clicks on the edited image, he sees the original image and when he removes his finger, the image is reverted back to original (something similar to what is on the original photos app in iOS). How can I do it?

I think I will have to use some Gesture recognizer, but I can't figure out which one.

I made a code by looking at a code on a stack overflow post which does this for a fixed period of 0.75s after the image is clicked. But this does not solve my purpose.

```
@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        tappedImage.image = originalImage
        imageState.text="Original"
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
            tappedImage.image = self.filteredImage
            self.imageState.text="Edited"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 approaches here:

- play with `highlighedImage` property of `UIImageView`
- override `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods
- use 2 imageViews for original and edited image